# How much minimum Ram to run jbpm

Tags: jbpm

How much minimum RAM to run jBPM?
We have Windows server 2012 with 4Gb RAM and if workflows build and deploy often, then  workflows deploying is broken over time. An exception occurs - "Exception cleaning and unsetting batch mode on FS". After this restart jbpm neccessary.
Maybe, this is because 96% RAM is occupied.
jBPM version is 6.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is about this
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/GUVNOR-2312

and has been resolved by JBPM team. It happened a lot to me when I was using jBPM 6.4. However never happened to 6.5.

In regard to memory:

I am using JBPM 6.5 docker for KIE-server and Workbench.

[image]

Here is information from docker stats.

It is only approximately around 1.5GB each. So, if you run those 2 services, it may consume up to 3GBs. I am not sure if you have other heavy services running. However, I think 4GBs is relatively too small. double the memory would be nice.

Also there is a configuration inside 
wildfly/bin/standalone.conf about heap space. It is by default 512M. You may need to increase it to 1024.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

To

`JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`"

Hope this helps.